# Cannot create directory on hadoop through hadoop web console

Tags: linux, hadoop, hadoop3

I have set up hadoop environment using a Linux VMWare image. I am able to create file and folder using Linux terminal

[image: creating dir2 using hadoop command]

But when I use the web interface to do the same, I get error:

> Permission denied: user=dr.who, access=WRITE,
>   inode="/":osboxes:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x

[image: error when using web interface]

Answer (score 0):

it says **permission denied** give you hadoop folder permission of your user

suppose your hadoop folder is in

```
/usr/local/hadoop
```

goto /usr/local
than use chown commond :

```
sudo chown -R yourusername yourfoldername
```

for more [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031026/how-to-change-the-owner-of-a-file-or-folder)

try this , see if it works...

Comment: the folder that I have created are available only in hadoop. so running the sugested command fails as Linux does not see teh "dir1" and "dir2". BTW, the osboxes already has write permission on those folders,